# how to shuffle a sparse vector in spark using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I have a sparse vector in spark and I want to randomly shuffle (reorder) its contents. This vector is actually a tf-idf vector and what I want is to reorder it so that in my new dataset the features have different order. is there any way to do this using scala?
this is my code for generating tf-idf vectors:

```
val tokenizer = new Tokenizer().setInputCol("text").setOutputCol("words")
val wordsData = tokenizer.transform(data).cache()
val cvModel: CountVectorizerModel = new CountVectorizer()
  .setInputCol("words")
  .setOutputCol("rawFeatures")
  .fit(wordsData)
val featurizedData = cvModel.transform(wordsData).cache()
val idf = new IDF().setInputCol("rawFeatures").setOutputCol("features")
val idfModel = idf.fit(featurizedData)
val rescaledData = idfModel.transform(featurizedData).cache()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is useful-

### Load the test data

```scala
 val data = Array(
      Vectors.sparse(5, Seq((1, 1.0), (3, 7.0))),
      Vectors.dense(2.0, 0.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0),
      Vectors.dense(4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 7.0)
    )
    val df = spark.createDataFrame(data.map(Tuple1.apply)).toDF("features")
    df.show(false)
    df.printSchema()

    /**
      * +---------------------+
      * |features             |
      * +---------------------+
      * |(5,[1,3],[1.0,7.0])  |
      * |[2.0,0.0,3.0,4.0,5.0]|
      * |[4.0,0.0,0.0,6.0,7.0]|
      * +---------------------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- features: vector (nullable = true)
      */
```

### shuffle the vector

```scala
val shuffleVector = udf((vector: Vector) =>
     Vectors.dense(scala.util.Random.shuffle(mutable.WrappedArray.make[Double](vector.toArray)).toArray)
   )

    val p = df.withColumn("shuffled_vector", shuffleVector($"features"))
    p.show(false)
    p.printSchema()

    /**
      * +---------------------+---------------------+
      * |features             |shuffled_vector      |
      * +---------------------+---------------------+
      * |(5,[1,3],[1.0,7.0])  |[1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,7.0]|
      * |[2.0,0.0,3.0,4.0,5.0]|[0.0,3.0,2.0,5.0,4.0]|
      * |[4.0,0.0,0.0,6.0,7.0]|[4.0,7.0,6.0,0.0,0.0]|
      * +---------------------+---------------------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- features: vector (nullable = true)
      * |-- shuffled_vector: vector (nullable = true)
      */
```

You can also use the above `udf` to create `Transformer` and put it in pipeline

> please make sure to use `import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg._`

### Update-1 convert shuffled vector to sparse

```scala
 val shuffleVectorToSparse = udf((vector: Vector) =>
      Vectors.dense(scala.util.Random.shuffle(mutable.WrappedArray.make[Double](vector.toArray)).toArray).toSparse
    )

    val p1 = df.withColumn("shuffled_vector", shuffleVectorToSparse($"features"))
    p1.show(false)
    p1.printSchema()

    /**
      * +---------------------+-------------------------------+
      * |features             |shuffled_vector                |
      * +---------------------+-------------------------------+
      * |(5,[1,3],[1.0,7.0])  |(5,[0,3],[1.0,7.0])            |
      * |[2.0,0.0,3.0,4.0,5.0]|(5,[1,2,3,4],[5.0,3.0,2.0,4.0])|
      * |[4.0,0.0,0.0,6.0,7.0]|(5,[1,3,4],[7.0,4.0,6.0])      |
      * +---------------------+-------------------------------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- features: vector (nullable = true)
      * |-- shuffled_vector: vector (nullable = true)
      */
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. when I try to do this I had problem with $ symbol in your code and had to change it to col("features"). Then in my dataset it had this error: cannot resolve 'UDF(features)' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires vector type, however, '`features`' is of struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>> type

Comment: when I execute printSchema function on my dataset the "features" column has vector type

Comment: which `Vector` have you imported ? use- `import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg._`

Comment: yes it works thank you man. but is there any chance to make the "shuffled_vector" feature sparse? this is so much memory consuming